# How does Transaction Merge really work?

Tags: opendaylight

I am repeating my unanswered question about MERGE operation. As I understand, to do MERGE md-sal has to read a tree into memory. Is it right? Can this read data be used for another MERGE within the same transaction or within the same transaction chain? If I need to do lots of merges of subtrees, will it improve performance if within the same transaction chain I preliminary read the entire tree that includes all these subtrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree is already fully stored in memory so it does not need to read it per transaction. When a transaction is created, it merely takes a snapshot of the current tree which is very fast. Subsequent transaction operations work on the snapshot, including reads. When a transaction is committed, the updates in the snapshot are validated and applied to in-memory tree.

Comment: What happens if the tree cannot fit the memory?

Comment: Then it run would run out of memory - one needs to appropriately size the maximum memory based on expected use. However the same issue could also occur if the tree was read into memory per transaction, not too mention the significant performance hit.